# Generic collection compile error without explicit cast - why?

Tags: java

added: this is Java 1.7 - as other people have pointed out in 1.8 it is fixed apparently

```
        Collection<Collection<String>> xx;

        // Fails
        xx = Collections.singleton( Collections.singleton( "hello" ) );

        // Succeeds
        xx = Collections.singleton( (Collection<String>)Collections.singleton( "hello" ) )
```

1. `Collections.singleton` returns `Set<T>` in this case `Set<String>`
2. `Set<T> extends Collection<T>`

The compiler error says `Expected <Collection<Collection<String>> but found <Set<Set<String>>` but according to 1 and 2 I believe this should be satisfied. The cast on the succeeds line seems redundant, why do I need to provide it?

Comment: Java 8 supports your first example. Earlier versions of Java did not.

Comment: Java 8 compiles it fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Collection<Collection<String>>` is not the same as a `Collection<Set<String>>` (as returned by `Collections.singleton()`). The compiler does **not** automatically convert these without an explicit cast (Except on Java 8, this runs fine). What I believe you are looking for is

```
Collection<? extends Collection<String>> xx;
```

This will allow `xx` to be assigned to any `Collection` whose elements are declared to be any subclass of `Collection`, including `Collection` itself.

Comment: Okay. It seems strange that an explicit cast is required or that an extension of Collection needs to be declared, when Collection is an interface so couldn't possibly be satisfied without an extension of some kind.

So it fails because the generic class could include a method which is incompatible with the subclass provided. Makes sense. Maybe.

Comment: Yes, it is strange. That's why it was fixed in Java 8.